# TimeMachine doesn't want to backup

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine

I'm using the most recent version of Mac OS X (Yosemite with Preview Update 3). However, when I want to activate the TimeMachine I get the error

```
The server may not exist or is unavalable at this time.  Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.
```

All other macs in this network can access the TimeMachine and make successful backups. Is there any known issue to this and if so, is there a fix?

Comment: At this time the most recent version of Mac OS X is 10.9.4. A developer preview tends to break things.

Comment: It's a beta version. There's a problem. Report it to Apple. They should tell you whether this is a bug / your problem.